# Verify app close ANDROID

Tags: android

I am conducting a background program that runs from x in x seconds to get new information. So far so good. The problem is that when I finish the application thread remains always active.

Is there any way to check if the application has ended?

thank you

Comment: Are you referring to your entire application or just an activity? Could you provide some code as to where you wish your application to exit. What are you currently trying?

Answer (score 0):

If your task should stop when the activity stops being shown, you should not *start* the service but *bind* it to the activity. The task then will be automatically stopped as soon as the activity has finished. If multiple activities should use the service, bind it to each of them.

[Here's](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html#Binding) how to bind the service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a Toast or AlertDialog box along with your code that finishes the activity to let you know that the application has ended.